# Input field being rendered as plain text

Tags: php, html

Im using PHP to render a page. I have echo statements such as

```
echo "<input type=\"text\" name=\"numPlate\" id=\"numPlate\" onblur=\"caps(this.id);\" $focusPlate required value=\"" . isset($_POST['numPlate']) ? $_POST['numPlate'] : "" ."\">";
```

but the value is being output as plain text rather than in the input field. If i take the ternary out then the input field is being rendered, which tells me that causes the issue, but i really don't understand why. The problem is is that I have about 20 other fields on this page in a similar fashion, so it's not a very clean solution to evaluate each of these statements to a variable and have the respective variables input into the value property.

Are there any other ways I could achieve this? Thanks

Edit:

Rendered html:

```
<div class="row"><label for="plate">Rendszám*</label>GMS245</div>
```

As you can see the string is just a text.

Comment: Can you included the rendered HTML in your question?

Comment: Although it won't fix your problem, you can clean up your code by not using double quotes instead use a single quote inside of your echo (replace `\"` with `'`). That way you won't have to escape everything. I would try wrapping your ternary in parentheses also.

Comment: That HTML has absolutely nothing to do with the PHP above.  Something else is going on.

Comment: @imvain2 thanks for the suggestion but the reason i am using double quotes is because some of these fields must be able to take variables too which is not possible with single quotes (to my knowledge)

Comment: And for the record, I personally would consider "evaluate each of these statements to a variable" to be a much cleaner solution.

Comment: @PatrickQ but if I take the ternary operator out of the statement the input field renders as required

Comment: @peterxz If the outer quotes are double-quotes, variables will be interpolated.  imvain2 was suggesting that you replace the _inner_ quotes (the escaped double-qoutes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested it out and I believe my second suggestion could solve it. Wrap the ternary in parenthesis. From my test, it was trying to evaluate the true response to the ternary instead of setting it as the value or ignoring it. I also replaced the inner quotes with a single quote to clean up the code while still allowing the variables to be evaluated.

```
echo "<input type='text' name='numPlate' id='numPlate onblur='caps(this.id);' $focusPlate required value='" . (isset($_POST['numPlate']) ? $_POST['numPlate'] : "") ."'>";
```

Comment: Operator precedence.  It was doing the concatenation (`"" ."\">"`) first

Comment: @PatrickQ, thank you. When I tried the code it kept telling me `Undefined index: numPlate`. So I assumed it was processing that first.

Comment: ah, I had a feeling I was forgetting something simple! I tried { } /facepalm thanks!